ERC20 Token Missing in Gnosis Safe UI (Transferred Before Safe Creation)
I'm having trouble with an ERC20 token on the base blockchain that isn't showing up in my Gnosis Safe UI. Since the transfer happened before the Safe's creation, I believe the indexer might not have captured it.
Could you advise on how to get the indexer to backfill this missing asset so it appears in my Safe UI? Any troubleshooting steps would be much appreciated.
I have the transaction hash for the transfer. Please let me know where to share.
